# is there any function for string comparision

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

```
    if(keccak256(products[i].category) != keccak256(category))
      eq=false;
```

Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from string storage ref to bytes memory requested. This function requires a single bytes argument

Answer (score 0):

You can compare strings using this

```
function compareStrings (string memory a, string memory b) public view returns (bool) {
    return (keccak256(abi.encodePacked((a))) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked((b))));
}
```

Refer [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/30914/50088) for original answer.